# Autofill numbers based on column

Tags: google-sheets

This may seem extremely elementary, however, I haven't been able to figure it out. I am wanting to be able to autofill a number series up to 6.

For example, the column would go from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 down each row, and then start over after 6. The columns in A2 would have the item and the columns in f are the position of the item in the gallery (crm requires 6 for each). Basically, it would repeat itself based on column A2. Is there a formula or an array type formula for this or something like it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula in cell F2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MOD(ROW(A2:A)-2,6)+1)
```

This would get the row number from A2, subtract by 2, divide by 6 and get the remainder, then add by 1.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(" "&
 QUERY(SEQUENCE(6, 1),,9^9), ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/6)),,9^9), " "))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a row-agnostic version based on **Carlos M**'s suggestion:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A)-ROW(),1,0),6)+1))
```

By "row agnostic," I mean that if the parallel range were moved to be A3:A or A5:A, etc., that is the only part of the formula that would need to be adjusted; the rest would accommodate without change.